# kick all users off mysql database

Tags: mysql

how can i do this without using the GUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SHOW PROCESSLIST` will list show the ids of the database connections.  Then `KILL ID` will disconnect the users.  A little Python script would do this nicely.

Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

connections=$( mysql -h$1 -u$2 -p$3 -e "SHOW PROCESSLIST" | grep $4 | awk '{print $1}' )

for id in $connections
do
    mysql -h$1 -u$2 -p$3 -e "KILL $id" 
done
```

usage:

kill.sh hostname username password SELECTION

SELECTION is a filter for grep, a username, client machine name, database, etc.

Answer (score 3):

On a Linux box, fist kill the daemon then start it again via root (`sudo` here):

`sudo killall mysqld`

Then

`sudo mysqld`

A better alternative is to use Ubuntu's service command:

`sudo service mysqld restart`

I'm not sure if other distros have it, but it's been around a while.

Sorry if I'm wrong here.

Answer (score -1):

Reset the daemon.

Comment: http://theos.in/desktop-linux/tip-that-matters/how-do-i-restart-mysql-server/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @tombom yeah, I've told several.people that in the 1.75 years since I posted this answer.